# Pico W Push Button not turning on the onboard LED

Tags: pi-pico, micropython, pi-pico-w

I am completely new to microcontroller in general and I am following along the kitronik discovery booklet. I have the circuit below built on my breadboard. When I run this circuit on wokwi.com it lights the LED as expected though on my actual breadboard it does not - see codes and screenshots below.

Any help would be very appreciated

```py
import machine

LED = machine.Pin("LED",machine.Pin.OUT)
BUTTON = machine.Pin(0,machine.Pin.IN,machine.Pin.PULL_DOWN)

while True:
    LED.value(BUTTON.value())
```

**actual breadboard**
[image]

**wokwi.com diagram**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as thought your header pins are not soldered onto the Pico.

You will not get good contact unless you solder the header pins to the pico.

Comment: It is a contact issue, indeed. Wiggling it around, I can have it work (turn on and off). Thank you for the help

Comment: Incredible... really.

Answer (score 0):

If the header is not really soldered with the pico board, please solder the header and place it on a breadboard like this:

https://images.theengineeringprojects.com/image/webp/2022/05/Interfacing-PIR-sensor-and-RPi-25.jpg.webp?ssl=1

If the problem is not gone, please test the continuities of your jumper wires too. You can also cross-check your code with this one:

https://www.hackster.io/Ramji_Patel/raspberry-pi-pico-and-button-321059